# proposal value between the generated data and the accepted previous proposal

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, julia

I have a question here that has been confusing me these two days. So in mcmc hasting metropolis if a proposal value was accepted which means tha it's going to be the current value after that `current=proposal`, then we generate another proposal after that to do the same process, but my question here is, does this next proposal value will be gotten from the data that has been generated for example `data=[for i in 1:N rand(distribution(argument_of_the_distribution))]`, `proposal=proposal_function(data[i])` or it will be proposed in function of the other accepted proposed value, `proposal= proposal_function(current)`